# Forgotten password on compressed file

Tags: password, compression, decompression

Two years ago, I did some data recovery for a client, and created a 7z compressed file with a password on the file. I have since forgotten the password i put on the file, the original hard drives are gone, and I have tried guessing the things I might commonly give for passwords on compressed user files.

Today, the Client wants his password, and I cant recall what it is, how can I decompress these files, and or recover the forgotten password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible solution which comes in my mind is to crack it by brute force. Rarcrack works with RAR and 7z as well.

Look at this page: [Rarcrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/)

To be honest, if you set very long password or/and have slow computer, it may take days to crack.

Comment: Actually, I just remembered what it was, but I certainly appreciate helpful utilities.